# Doubt about independent and dependent events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

For example:
[image]

An airport screens bags for forbidden items, and an alarm is supposed to be triggered when a forbidden item is detected.

Suppose that $5\%$ of bags contain forbidden items.
If a bag contains a forbidden item, there is a $98\%$ chance that it triggers the alarm.
If a bag doesn't contain a forbidden item, there is an $8\%$, percent chance that it triggers the alarm.

$P(F\cap A)=(0.05)(0.98)=0.049$

$P(A)=P(F∩A)+P(N∩A)
=0.049+0.076
=0.125
$
$P(F) = 0.05$, right?

$P(F∣A)=0.392$
So, are these events independent or dependent?

So they are not independent right? $P(F∣A)=0.392 \neq P(F) = 0.05$ ? But why we an calculate $P(F∩A)$ as $P(F)P(A)$ ? Isn't this case/formula only for independent events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why we an calculate $\mathbb P(F\cap A)$ as $\mathbb P(F)\mathbb P(A)$ ? Isn't this case/formula only for independent events?

You are actually calculating it as $\mathbb P(F\cap A)=\mathbb P(F)\mathbb P(A|F)$ because the following sentence

> If a bag contains a forbidden item, there is a 98% , percent chance
>   that it triggers the alarm

means that $\mathbb P(A|F)=0.98$, not $\mathbb P(A)$ because of the part "If a bag contains a forbidden item", which means $F$ is on the *given* side of the expression.

Comment: That's right, thanks Gunes! Good job.

Comment: Could reference me some site/course or book on probability? Maybe with lots of exercises.

Comment: I personally find Intro to Prob from Dimitri Bertsekas - MIT Press, very enlightening, examples are quite sophisticated.

Comment: Gunnes, why do you shift A and F? P(F∩A) = P(A|F)*P(F) instead of P(F∩A) = P(F|A)*P(F) , isn't this last formula the standard one? When we see the definition of conditional probability we use the second formula not the first.

Comment: @JoãoVitorGomes No, the first one is true.